# Does a WCF Web Service, when invoked, use the config file of the invoking application?

Tags: wcf, web-config, invoke

Assume that I have an **ASP.NET application** and a **WCF Web Service**, both deployed on IIS 7.

One of my colleagues claims that when an ASP.NET application redirects the response to **WCF Web Service**, the **WCF Web Service** does not refer to its config file but to that of the ASP.NET application (or at least its **appSettings** section). I really think this statement is really wrong but my colleague has more experience so I after argumenting a bit I let it go.

But then I though, since the web service is used just when it is invoked by another application, what's the use of the config file in the WCF Web Service if it never uses it?

Comment: Why are you redirecting to the service? Why aren't you just using "Add Service Reference" and calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response.Redirect results in completely new request from client to the new address. This basically means it is just as any other request to the second address so Service on second URL wont have any idea about website from first URL.

[Response.Redirect vs Server.Transfer](http://haacked.com/archive/2004/10/06/responseredirectverseservertransfer.aspx)

So the answer would be no, WCF service will not use web.config from ASP.NET site but its own.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your description I can make out that the ASP.Net application will call the WCF service i.e. will act as the client for the service.

The ASP.Net application will need to have a reference to the endpoint and some other details about the service in order to be able to call the service. These details will become part of the ASP.Net Web.config file.

The service will need to have its own details defined in its own config file such as endpoints, behaviours, security details etc. etc.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, maybe my question was a bit misleading since I misused the term invoke. Suppose that I have an ASP.NET 4 application and at the URL http://my.service.com. Than if from the application I do Response.Redirect("http://my.service.com", false) does your answer applies?